# Adding URL links in table charts

Tags: html, apache-superset

We have a Superset table that displays data based on an SQL query. Currently, all the data is rendered in HTML div/span tags.

We need to open a link in a new tab on click of one of the columns. If we send the raw link in anchor tag, it displays `<a href={{link}}></a>`, because the superset code wraps all the contents in a div/span tag.

Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 8):

As far as **superset** use `df.to_html` to render the pandas data frames to Html on `Dahsoborads` `Explore` Tabs, you can use HTML tags and other on your queries. For example, I developed this simple query that generates a simple table of charts with CSV download links. Check This out:

1. Write The query like this:

[image]

2. Try to explore it(click on the explore button!):

[image]

Comment: @Mahesh I did this on superset 0.34! what is your problem rendering HTML or wrong url?

Comment: I wrote query to get a string like this <a href="https://google.com">Google</a> and when used in table, it is showing the actual string but not as url. I am on version 0.999.0 dev

Comment: Try to explore it! I will edit my answer that may help you

Comment: Thankyou it works. Initially I created a chart and edited my query and that dint work. When I create the query from SQLLab and explore it works!! Not sure what was the difference. Will explore sometime and update the answer here.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, you can't. All visualization on superset is based on d3. You might want to look for custom visualizations on their site.